# Process with Markov property but not strong Markov property

Tags: stochastic-processes

I'm trying to find a simple example of a stochastic process with the Markov property, but not the [strong Markov property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_property#Strong_Markov_Property), to give me an intuitive understanding of the distinction between them.

All the processes I can think of off the top of my head seem to have either both or neither of these properties.

Thanks.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/43833/a-markov-process-which-is-not-a-strong-markov-process/43838#43838

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An example is $X_t=\max\{t-T,0\}$, where $T$ is exponentially distributed.

For every fixed nonnegative $t$,  conditionally on $\mathscr F_t^X$, $(X_{t+s})_{s\ge0}$ is distributed like $(X_s)_{s\ge0}$ on $[X_t=0]$ and like $(X_t+s)_{s\ge0}$ on $[X_t>0]$. But $(X_{T+s})_{s\ge0}$  is not distributed like $(X_s)_{s\ge0}$ on $\Omega=[X_T=0]$.

Comment: As @Byron explained on MO.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, imagine a process whose volatility is time-dependent:
$dF_t = f(t) dW_t$.  This is Markov, since the distribution of future states only depends on the present state, but it is not strong Markov, because the distribution of $F_{\tau + t} - F_{\tau}$ is not independent of $\tau$.